# How can I reference a field from another model in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to link some fields from the User model in the Card schema based on the username.
So for example this is my Card schema

```
 const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
      username: {
       type: String,
       ref: 'User',
       required: true
      },
      userSticker: {
       This is what I need to get from the user model based on the username or user id
      }
```

And this is what the user model looks like:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  userSticker: {
   type: String,
  }
```

What I would need is to have always in the Card schema the same userSticker as the user with that username has. Adding it when the card is created will not work because the userSticker may change and I would like the field to change in the Card schema too when that happens, so I guess it should be something like a reference.

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database. You need to change both field or use SQL.

Comment: Change both fields ?

Comment: I know it's a bummer but when you change userSticker in User collection you have to update all userSticker in Card collection matching the user.

Comment: As an alternative you can also manually reference your collection but this require multiple fetch.

Comment: I will post an answer trying my best to explain both solution.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Okay so I've read that mongoose does this for you. It can model your tables relationally and populate relational data based on the ref you defined in the schema.

Check this out [Relational database design to mongoDB/mongoose design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924616/relational-database-design-to-mongodb-mongoose-design)

*This section is for MongoDB*

There is two solution here since MongoDB is not a relational database like SQL.

**First solution** is to duplicate the data and update all fields whenever the field value change

```
const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  userSticker: {
    type: String,
  }
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  userSticker: {
    type: String,
  }
})
```

then whenever userSticker change you need to query card collection and update all userSticker matching the username

**Second solution** is two create manually a reference between collections

```
const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: String
  }
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  userSticker: {
    type: String,
  }
})
```

then when you query the document card collection you can do a second query for the document referenced by user_id

- First one is slower on write but faster on read
- Second one is faster on write but slower on read (paginate your query)

Answer (score 0):

From official mongoose docs [Query Population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
 const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
      username: {
       type: String,
       ref: 'User',
       required: true
      },
      userSticker: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
       ref: 'User'
      }
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  userSticker: {
   type: String,
  }
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema);

Card.findbyId(id).populate('userSticker', 'userSticker').exec(function(err, card) {/* Do stuff... */})
```